# How do i populate my Form from my data saved in localstorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, forms, local-storage

I want to populate a form I made with this value I have saved in the localstorage.

```
var vm;
  vm = this;
  vm.data = {};

  var memberData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('memberData'));
  vm.data.mobile =  memberData.mobile;
```

This is the form i want to populate:

```
<div class="item item-icon-left"><i class="icon ion-iphone assertive"></i><span  class="label">Mobile</span><span class="item-note">
 <input type="tel" name="mobile" placeholder="Contact" ng-model="profile.data.mobile" required="required" style="background-color:transparent;"/>
  <div class="helpers" ng-if="profileForm.mobile.$touched">
                  <span ng-if="profileForm.mobile.$error.required" class="help-block" style="color:red;">Enter a Phone No.!</span>
                  </div>
                </span>
                </div>
```

Comment: It is not understandable. Will you please elaborate more or create a fiddle ?

Comment: So I have a Js file which is my controller that has all my values , now i've save all the value(mobile) in the local storage. I want to then fill up my empty form with that data(mobile), but im not sure how, im new to js and angular framework. thx for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your forms are input tags as in the example, this can be done easily by selecting the element and setting `value` attribute to what you want it to be, for example (in your case):

```
  // since your input has no ID, we'll use getElementsByName instead
  // this returns an array of elements, so we'll choose the first one
  // using an ID would be better practice
  var mobileInput = document.getElementsByName('mobile')[0];

  // then we modify the value attribute with your value from above
  mobileInput.value = vm.data.mobile;
```

Read up on the attribute and other related things at [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp) or look at [Mozzila's specs on the input tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) for hints on how you can play with it using JavaScript!

Comment: so currently it's a input type= tell, can i make vm.data.mobile as a place holder? I want the user to see that they can update the form. Thank you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/not_inept/as22rkoL/1/

Is this what you mean? You can access most attributes using `element.attribute = value`. The placeholder being accessible at `element.placeholder`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `ng-controller="[Controller] as profile"` in your view? If not, then

`vm.data.mobile =`

should be changed to

`vm.profile.data.mobile =`

Comment: I separated the Js file which is my controller and the html as a blank form. Thanks for the help, im new to angular js and html5